# How to remove the hardcoded endpoints in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, next.js13

I have a working code:

```
import { AnyARecord } from "dns";

import client from "@/lib/fetchWrapper";

export default async function addProductImage({
  photo,
  productId,
}: {
  photo: File;
  productId: string;
}) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("productId", productId);
  formData.append("images", photo);
  console.log("==photo==", Object.values(photo));
  const files =Object.values(photo)
  const token =
    localStorage.getItem("ecommerceToken") ||
    sessionStorage.getItem("ecommerceToken");
 
for (const key in files) {
        formData.append('images', files[key as string])
      }
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4005/v1/product-image", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
  });
```

But since I don't want to use the hardcoded endpoint `http://localhost:4005/v1/product-image`. SO, a fetch wrapper function has been created.

```
export default function client(
  endpoint: string,
  { body, ...customConfig }: any = {}
) {
  const token =
    localStorage.getItem("ecommerceToken") ||
    sessionStorage.getItem("ecommerceToken");
  const headers = { "content-type": "application/json", Authorization: "" };
  if (token) {
    headers.Authorization = Bearer ${token};
  }
  const config = {
    method: body ? "POST" : "GET",
    ...customConfig,
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      ...customConfig.headers,
    },
  };
  if (body) {
    config.body = JSON.stringify(body);
  }

  return fetch(${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/${endpoint}, config).then(
    async (response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return await response.json();
      } else {
        const error = await response.json();
        return Promise.reject(new Error(error?.message));
      }
    }
  );
}
```

After making adjustments to my code using fetchwrapper

```
import client from "@/lib/fetchWrapper";

export default async function addProductImage({
  photo,
  productId,
}: {
  photo: File;
  productId: string;
}) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("productId", productId);

  Object.values(photo).forEach((img) => formData.append("images", img));

  const response = await client("v1/product-image", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', // Set Content-Type header
    },
  });

  return response;

}
```

I received errors while using the fetchwrapper

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": [
        "productId must be a string",
        "productId should not be empty"
    ],
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

I tried consoling `productId` , it returns a valid string and non empty string. I also tried consoling `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL` and `endpoint`. They also return valid data. I suspect it is wrong the `client` function. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `FormData` to store `productId` and stringifying it using `JSON.stringify`. When you `JSON.stringify` a formdata object, you get empty object. Hence the error.
You need to convert the formdata to a normal javascript object and then stringify it.

```js
config.body = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(body));
```

Comment: on payload, there is productid now, but images is empty still but I still have error message now