# How to convert a list of files from a formdata to JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch-api

I have a form data which consists of multiple images under the same product id.

```
import client from "@/lib/fetchWrapper";

export default async function addProductImage({
  photo,
  productId,
}: {
  photo: File[];
  productId: string;
}) {
  if (!productId || typeof productId !== "string") {
    throw new Error("productId must be a non-empty string.");
  }

  try {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("productId", productId);

    if (!photo || photo.length === 0) {
      throw new Error("No image files found.");
    }

    // Append each image to the FormData
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      formData.append('images[]', file[i])
}
    formData.forEach((value, key) => {
      console.log(key, value);
    });
    
    const formDataObj = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());
    console.log(formDataObj)


    const response = await client("v1/product-image", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formDataObj,
       headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    });

    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error uploading product images:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

I tried uploading three images and all three images are displayed while consoling the formdata:

```
productId 5b1a763a-4867-4bd8-a47b-f6d1f4642863
addProductImage.ts:55 images[] 
File {name: 'durga-puja-parvati-ganesha-hinduism-png-favpng-aFuv1A72aKarGGLjPzqwaBKy1_t.png', 
lastModified: 1697095379428, 
lastModifiedDate: Thu Oct 12 2023 13:07:59 GMT+0545 (Nepal Time),
 webkitRelativePath: '', size: 48632, …}lastModified: 1697095379428lastModifiedDate: Thu Oct 12 2023 13:07:59 GMT+0545 (Nepal Time) {}name: "durga-puja-parvati-ganesha-hinduism-png-favpng-aFuv1A72aKarGGLjPzqwaBKy1_t.png"size: 48632type: "image/png"webkitRelativePath: ""[[Prototype]]: File
addProductImage.ts:55 images[] File {name: 'durga-puja-parvati-ganesha-hinduism-png-favpng-aFuv1A72aKarGGLjPzqwaBKy1_t.jpeg', lastModified: 1697090823881, lastModifiedDate: Thu Oct 12 2023 11:52:03 GMT+0545 (Nepal Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 15891, …}
addProductImage.ts:55 images[] File {name: 'drug copy.png', lastModified: 1687005222158, lastModifiedDate: Sat Jun 17 2023 18:18:42 GMT+0545 (Nepal Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 45617, …}
addProductImage.ts:59
```

But when I convert the the formdata into JavaScript object using `const formDataObj = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());`

Only, `productId` is displayed in the payload not the array of images.

The `fetchwrapper` code:

```
export default function client(
  endpoint: string,
  { body, ...customConfig }: any = {}
) {
  const token =
    localStorage.getItem("ecommerceToken") ||
    sessionStorage.getItem("ecommerceToken");
  const headers = { "content-type": "application/json", Authorization: "" };
  if (token) {
    headers.Authorization = Bearer ${token};
  }
  const config = {
    method: body ? "POST" : "GET",
    ...customConfig,
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      ...customConfig.headers,
    },
  };
  if (body) {
    config.body = JSON.stringify(body);
  }

  return fetch(${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/${endpoint}, config).then(
    async (response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return await response.json();
      } else {
        const error = await response.json();
        return Promise.reject(new Error(error?.message));
      }
    }
  );
}
```

The error on the response part is:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": [
        "productId must be a string",
        "productId should not be empty"
    ],
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

But, I still see a valid `productId` in the payload.

After doing the fix from Jared, when consoling the `formDataObj`, I see the files under the same product key. But on the payload, it's missing. So how to send the data under the body of http request.

Payload:

```
{productId: "61918f7f-e338-42fd-a79e-128c3d9539ec", images: [{}, {}, {}]}
images
: 
[{}, {}, {}]
0
: 
{}
1
: 
{}
2
: 
{}
productId
: 
"61918f7f-e338-42fd-a79e-128c3d9539ec"
```

Comment: This question can be summarized as [“How to convert FormData to JSON”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431322/how-to-convert-formdata-html5-object-to-json) because that is what you are ending up doing here `const response = await client("v1/product-image", { method: "POST", body: formDataObj, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`

Comment: Also note `formDataObj` is a JavaScript object and cannot be sent as the body of a Http/1.1 request because Http/1.1 body takes text i.e. characters. It also takes raw bytes with header `Content-Type: octet-stream`

Comment: So, what would be the fix, I cannot send formDataObj only `productId` with string is seen and on the response side, the issue is same.  I have uploaded the payload section

Comment: See this [MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#sending_files_using_a_formdata_object) to learn how to upload files using form data.

Comment: I can send directly from the form data, the situation arised when I tried to remove the hardcoded endpoints from the http request part. More detailed situation is described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77382276/how-to-remove-the-hardcoded-endpoints-in-react/77382420#77382420 . Can you please check this  @ChukwujiobiCanon

Comment: Why not use the browsers `fetch` API like you pointed out in that comment at the other question?

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon I have used the fetch API but there's something wrong with the fetchwrapper that was created; So while removing the hardcoded one, I got issue fixing that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255784/discussion-between-atom-store-and-chukwujiobi-canon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can convert FormData to JSON. [This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46774073) lists multiple ways to do that but you should probably ask yourself why. [See when to use FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#:%7E:text=The%20FormData%20object%20lets%20you,order%20to%20transmit%20keyed%20data.) especially when uploading `Blobs` and or `Files`.

Comment: The solution worked it was just a minor error. Needed to remove the explicit content type while using fetch when sending form data.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a duplicate but the answers I found when searching ranged from incomplete to terrible, so here we go:

You cannot naively convert a FormData using `Object.fromEntries` because FormData can hold multiple entries for a given key but JS objects are LWW (Last Write Wins) for a given key. For example:

```
const foo = new FormData();
foo.append('bar', 1);
foo.append('bar', 2);
const obj = Object.fromEntries(foo);
console.log(obj); // { bar: 2 }
foo.forEach(console.log); // bar: 1, bar: 2!
```

Note that you're appending the same key `images[]` over and over in your loop.

Here's a general purpose conversion function that will turn multiple entries at the same key into an array:

```
const formDataToObj = (fd) => {
  const result = {};
  fd.forEach((val, key) => {
    // NOTE: FormData converts all values
    // to strings, this will convert e.g.
    // numbers and bools back
    let value = val;
    try {
      value = JSON.parse(value);
    } catch (err) {
      // pass
    }

    if (key in result) {
      if (Array.isArray(result[key])) {
        result[key].push(value);
      } else {
        result[key] = [result[key], value];
      }
    } else {
      result[key] = value;
    }
  });

  return result;
};
```

Comment: This will be problematic if `FormData` contains `Blob`

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon good call out.

Answer (score 1):

Mine is similar to Jared but I think JSON.parse is unnecessary since you have to convert it back to JSON string so it can be sent in http request.
Also JSON.parse cab be expensive to compute if you have large/nested object.

```
/** @param {FormData} formdata */
const convertFormDataToObject = (formdata) => {

  /** @type {Record<string, unknown>} **/
  const resultObj = Object.create(null) // prevent prototype pollution

  for (const [key, fvalue] of formdata) {
    let existingValue = resultObj[key]
    if (existingValue) {
      if (Array.isArray(existingValue)) existingValue.push(fvalue)
      else resultObj[key] = [existingValue, fvalue]
    } else {
      resultObj[key] = fvalue
    }
  }

  return resultObj
}
```

Comment: "JSON.parse cab be expensive to compute if you have large/nested object" you're not wrong, but most people aren't sending large JSON strings as the values from their HTML forms.